# Export flash from Unity 4.x

Tags: flash, unity-game-engine

I have licensed Unity 3D 4.3.4f1. And I do not see build for flash. I can see Android, iOS, WEB and others but no flash. I have read somewhere that Unity no longer support flash. So how can I still export SWF or use flash some how. I need it very badly because I have an old project in Flash that I need to add features from Unity to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can export for Flash Player anymore.

According to [this](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/04/23/sunsetting-flash/) they will support **existing customers**. So if you don't have an existing license I don't think Unity is gonna sell another one.

You could try to get your hands on a Unity 4.2 or something older, I remember that 4.2 had the option to export to Flash Player.